Copying data from destination tab to source tabs automatically
I have a macro in excel that copies data from 5 tabs into one tab that is the master data file, and then into another where it hides some columns. Each time the macro is being ran, it deletes all the data from the two destination tabs. Everything works fine, but I would like to have an option to manually enter a comment in the destination tab and have it copied to the source tab. Is it even possible without altering the macro dramatically? The columns that are being hidden might be changed in the future and I would like to avoid having to change the macro every time they are.
This is the macro that I currently run. It works fine. All of the tables are in the same format, the data itself starts in the 3rd row and the comments that I would like to have would be in column "AQ"
Sub ConsolidateData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheetStakeholders As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sourceSheets As Variant
    Dim sheetName As Variant
    Dim columnsToHide As Variant
    
    ' Define source sheets
    sourceSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")
    
    ' Define destination sheets
    Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects consolidated")
    Set destSheetStakeholders = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination tab 2")
    
    ' Clear existing data from destination sheets (starting from row 3)
    destSheet.Rows("3:" & destSheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    destSheetStakeholders.Rows("3:" & destSheetStakeholders.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    ' Initialize destination rows
    destRow = 3
    
    ' Define columns to hide in Destination tab 2
    columnsToHide = Array("O", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP") ' Adjust as needed
    
    For Each sheetName In sourceSheets
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        If lastRow > 2 Then
            ' Define the range to copy (all columns, from row 3 to last row)
            Set rng = ws.Range("A3:AP" & lastRow)
            
            ' Copy data to consolidated and stakeholders view
            destSheet.Cells(destRow, 1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
            destSheetStakeholders.Cells(destRow, 1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
            
            ' Hide specified columns in Destination tab 2
            For Each col In columnsToHide
                destSheetStakeholders.Columns(col).Hidden = True
            Next col
            
            ' Update destination rows
            destRow = destRow + rng.Rows.Count
        End If
    Next sheetName
End Sub


Where should the comment be copied to specifically? The same row? A solution might be to use the Workbook.SheetChange event.

Can you give some sample data for your source and destination worksheets, and an example of what an updated row of the source worksheet might look like?

I can't give you any samples unfortunately. Each row in the source tabs correspond to an event. I might need to leave a comment or a note on some of the events to let other people know. I don't want to go to each tab separately and look for specific events. The comment column is the last column of the table. I want the comment to be moved from the destination sheet to the source sheet, to the corresponding row. Hope this helps, if not, please let me know.

To reliably match the rows between the sheets you'd need to track which destination row came from which source row - does your data have unique identifiers or something you could use to figure out which exact source row needs to get the comment?

FYI you don't need to do this part For Each col In columnsToHide until after you're finished moving data.

Yes, each event has a unique title that can be used to track them.
